# Javascript image enlarger question

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I tried using this script:

http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/thumbnail.html

I've successfully generated the said `img` attributes on my website, however it does not seem to work. When I click on the image, nothing happens.

The generated script looks like this:

```
<img ondbclick="javascript:photo_6969.height=80px;
photo_6969.width=150px" onclick="javascript:photo_6969.height=241px;
photo_6969.width=450px" name="photo_6969" 
src="-----" height="80px" width="150px">
```

It is exactly the same as on the script, but it does not seem to work at all. I just need a simple image enlarger script.

My firefox error console says this:

```
Error: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
Source File: ----------------
Line: 1, Column: 29
Source Code:
javascript:photo_6969.height=241px;photo_6969.width=450px
```

(I've ----- out the image links)

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net/ my friend.  We can't help much if we can't see your code.

Comment: Or better: input your code here. That's why there's a code-button `{}`... That code looks horrible to me, BTW, there's no need for `javascript:` in inline event handler attributes and there's no function call.

Comment: This is some nasty code.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, but that is the only code I have as per this site's instructions http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/thumbnail.html Is this a bad tutorial or what? It works on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<img ondblclick="this.height=80;this.width=150" onclick="this.height=241;this.width=450" src="-----" height="80px" width="150px" />
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/caAvW/

---

changes made

1. do not use `px` at the end, just the number
2. use `this.` instead of the name (*`photo_6969.`*) you have applied.
3. `ondbclick` should really be `ondblclick`

Answer (score 1):

ondblclick, not ondbclick.  Also width and height attributes of dom elements are integers, they do not have "px" appended.